# For test-ability, we avoid "new" and use Dependency Injection. What about "new" in an object's method argument?

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit, tdd

I understand this **IS NOT** easily testable/mockable:

```
public function index(){

    $jedi = new Jedi(); // <-- "new" operator used here

    ...
}
```

Using Dependency Injection, I understand this **IS** now easily testable/mockable:

```
public function index(JediInterface $jedi){

    $jedi->doSomething();

    ...
}
```

But does it matter about the method arguments? Consider this code below, **is it also easily testable/mockable?**

```
public function index(JediInterface $jedi){

    $jedi->setLightSaber(new BlueLightsaber()); // <-- "new" operator used in argument

    return $jedi->getLightsaberColor();
}
```

*Note:
The $jedi class has the method definition:*
 
`public function setLightSaber(LightSaberInterface $saber)`

Comment: not only for testing purpose but for software maintainability also. I suggest you to substitute the object creation with any Creational patterns.

Comment: So the third code snippet is not easily testable? Also, when you say "software maintainability", consider that `->setLightSaber` method accepts type-hinted interface. You don't see that there, because you don't see the class code for $jedi in this example.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote. I took good time to phrase the question, and have been researching it.

Comment: hi sir, i don't downvote your question and i hope who have done that will comment with motivation. IMHO seems a normal dubious and +1 for you

Comment: Nothing wrong with testabillity, but it tightly couples the class::index to a `new BlueLightsaber()` concrete..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the constructor of a BlueLightSaber has absolutely **no side-effects** and you don't see the type of lightsaber changing in the near future, I'd keep your implementation the way it is. Adding indirection always introduces extra complexity.

As for testability, you are now testing whether a Jedi works correctly with a BlueLightSaber (i.e. you are writing integrated tests rather than isolated tests for just the jedi), but that doesn't have to be a problem per se. While it's true that when integrated tests fail it will be more difficult to pinpoint the exact problem, if the lightsaber truly is an implementation detail of the jedi you're perhaps better of writing an integrated test. Isolated tests tend to get in the way of future refactorings when they know too much about the implementation details.

(more information on isolated vs integrated tests [here](http://www.jbrains.ca/permalink/integrated-tests-are-a-scam-part-1))

Another point worth mentioning: you are mixing a query (get lightsaber color) with logic that changes state (set lightsaber) in a single method invocation. This might be confusing for developers that use your code and can often be separated for better understandability. This principle is called [Command-Query Separation](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandQuerySeparation.html) (CQS). Also, I tend to avoid changing state of input arguments (the jedi) as much as possible, as it can lead to the same confusing bugs as violating CQS.

Comment: +1 For this breakdown. Btw, I've been totally enjoying applying CQS (maybe some day look into more complicated CQRS and ES) to my app and I would also recommend it (especially with Domain Driven Design).

Answer (score 1):

No, becasuse the object is created inside the mehod. Imagine, how would you substitute BlueSaber with ChainSaw in a different program that uses index()?

Comment: The $jedi class has `public function setLightSaber(LightSaberInterface $saber)`. You can pass chainsaw if you want, as long as it implements LightSaberInterface.

Comment: I think people are getting confused because of the second code snippet implied I would want to "substitute" out the argument in "setLightSaber". See updated question. I'm asking if I can easily test that return value in the third snippet.

Comment: Yeah, but you are still using new Object instead of $this->property. You can't test it.

Answer (score 1):

It will affect the testability. Maybe not inmediately, but it will when you need to test some object that works different depending on the saber color (here it is alway blue and you can't change that). You can argue that in this exact example that does not happen, but in general, it will.

Also, maybe in the future you want to alter the way BlueLightsaber works, so it will log some info when being created. If you can't mock it, real logs will be written when testing.

There are lots of reasons. The better and harder way to learn them is trying to test legacy code plagued with direct object instantiations.